# Can't push Angular project - Github

Tags: angular, github, git-push

So I'm trying to push my angular project to Github. The project structure is:

- backend (Node API)
- frontend (Angular)
- .gitignore

In order to push the angular project, I positioned myself in the root folder and executed the following commands:

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "First commit"
3. git remote add origin URL_OF_MY_REPO
4. git push -u origin master

The backend is pushed without any apparent issues, but the frontend will only push an empty folder as shown:

[image]

The file **.gitignore** only includes `node_modules` to avoid pushing the node_modules folder (which works, as the node_modules is not being pushed).

However, the frontend is not being pushed at all.

Comment: Can you provide us the `.gitignore` content, and the main structure/folders names of the project?

Comment: It only has 'node_modules' and it works! As the node_modules folder is not being pushed in the backend folder

Comment: Could the issue be related to the size of the project? (It's a pretty big project)

Comment: try doing  "git add ." before creating your commit

Comment: I'll update the post to give more information

Comment: is there a second .gitignore inside of the frontend folder?

Comment: Yep, but I removed them as well with the same result. I thought that the issue may be the size of the project, but there were no error logs during the push

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that when you run the `ng new` command, it creates a git repository along with the angular project.
When git finds a repository inside another repository it only commits the reference to that repository which is what you show in the image as the folder with an arrow.
To solve this issue, you can

1. Remove the .git folder (if it exists) in the frontend folder
2. Then copy the folder to another location and delete the one at the repository.
3. Make a commit with these changes
4. Copy the frontend code back to the repository (make sure there is no .git folder in it)
5. Commit the changes
6. Push

From what I have experienced, it solved the problem when I had it.